# Error: reading API Gateway REST API (nkrcj743be): AccessDeniedException:

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I have a terraform resource block below which manages API Gateway REST API.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  tags = local.tags
  name = local.name_prefix
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "metering" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:

Error: reading API Gateway REST API (nkrcj743be): AccessDeniedException:
│   status code: 403, request id:

I have attached the following policies to my Terraform user:

```
        "apigateway:GetRestApi",
        "iam:GetRole",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "apigateway:GetResources",         
        "apigateway:GetRestApis",       
        "apigateway:GetAccount",
        "apigateway:GetMethod",
        "apigateway:GetIntegration",
        "apigateway:GetDeployment",
        "apigateway:GetStage",
```

Any ideas what required permissions I am missing here?

Comment: check cloudtrail events which should tell you which permission is missing and causing the 403 to deny the request

Comment: yes thanks @ChrisDoyle. I was able to figure it by looking at cloud trail

Comment: It would help to share what the solution was as an answer to your own question, so that future readers with a similar problem can benefit from what you learned.